# How do I diagnose random UI slowness and slow ssh connection initiation for several minutes after a reboot?

Tags: performance

The boot sequence opens up Kodi in full screen. That comes up fine. But when I try to initiate an `ssh` connection it will often just simply time out. This lasts for about 10 minutes after a reboot. There's also a lot of UI slowness: a window drag will take a few seconds to respond. Checked `top`, CPU is never above 20%, memory is fine.

Answer (score 10):

(You've solved your specific problem, but I'm posting some general advice for people encountering a similar problem.)

On many systems, if you turn your computer off at night and boot it or wake it up from suspension in the morning, it'll run various daily jobs, via [anacron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anacron). This starts a few minutes after the computer wakes up, so you'd typically have time to log in but the resource usage would intensify after a few minutes. Anacron jobs are configured in `/etc/anacrontab`; a common configuration is for it to run the jobs listed in `/etc/cron.daily`. Maybe one of these jobs is using an unreasonable amount of resources for some reason. Use a tool like `pstree` to check what children of `anacron` are running.

You've found that there isn't much CPU usage. Given your description, the most likely culprit is extreme memory pressure, where your normal activity is competing with some program that also wants all the memory for itself, so the system keeps thrashing, i.e. it keeps having to move data memory into swap and back out, and to load parts of running programs and data that would normally stay in the disk cache. [iotop](http://guichaz.free.fr/iotop/) can give you an idea of disk activity.

Check the system logs under `/var/log`. `ls -ltr /var/log` will let you know which ones were modified the most recently; check the ones that kept being written after you logged in. The contents may offer a clue.

Comment: "Given your description, the most likely culprit is extreme memory pressure" -- but in the top post it says memory is fine. It never went above 30% when I was seeing the slowdowns.

Comment: I am still seeing some occasional slowness when hitting the NAS for file listings etc so I think there are still issues to track down

Comment: But thanks for offering advice, I think it will help anyone who finds this question in the future

Answer (score 5):

I found the reason for this a few minutes after I started writing this up but I'd prefer to leave the question up in case it helps anyone else.

I noticed that `systemd` was the first entry in `top` quite often. This led me to check my logs:

```
ls -alht /var/log
```

First entry `syslog`, was 5GB. WOW. OK that told me something was wrong. Then I ran:

```
journalctl -f
```

Which showed a ton of USB errors -- to the tune of 100 per second -- with an error like `Error: urb status = -32`. I tracked down the USB issue* (problem with an external USB signal receiver) and the issue went away.

* sorry, revealing more info might give away an account I'd prefer to keep anonymous.

Comment: We don't care about your account so you're safe there. But if I had an issue with an external USB receiver I'd be very thankful if you finished your thought here.

Comment: I'm not going to reveal that account -- it's for my own safety. I'll give you a hint: it had to do with an HTPC IR receiver.

Comment: It would be very informational if you could show some relevant log lines (with private data removed or replaced, obviously).  This would help other readers with similar issues. The issue can't "go away" by the act of viewing a log file, so what Corey is asking about is what it was in the log that pointed your to the correct resolution and what it prompted you to do to actually resolve your issue.  In its current state, your answer is essentially a non-answer.

Comment: Made an edit. There's really nothing more to add, the error message is only a handful of characters beyond what I added.